# Reverse minesweeper?

Tags: enigmatic-puzzle, cipher, grid-deduction, minesweeper

The puzzle below, when filled out completely, is a valid minesweeper board.

Some of the mines and numbers have already been filled in.

Can you fill in what is missing and use the solved grid to find a hidden phrase?

[image]

---

Hint 1:

> The hidden phrase contains 9 characters (7 are letters)

Hint 2:

> Each character is represented in the grid by 3 digits.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The solved grid (solved independently of @Glorfindel - pipped to the initial posting of the completed grid by seconds!) is as follows:

> [image]

What's crucial here is to:

> Make sure to enter the relevant 'minesweeper' number into all the green blanks (i.e. the number of mines in the 8 adjacent squares).

This then gives us:

> 27 digits on green squares. As we are looking for a 9-character phrase, these naturally group into triplets:
>
>  078/105/067/101/032/074/111/066/033

What do we have now? Well, notice that these numbers:

> fall nicely into the range in [ASCII](https://ascii.cl/) used for standard letter and punctuation characters. If we translate these triplets into ASCII (noting that 032 is a space and 033 is an exclamation mark), we see the final phrase:
>
>  **NiCe JoB!**

Answer (score 6):

Here is the solved grid:

> [image]

but I'm not sure (yet) what to do next ...

Comment: Do you know why some squares are green?

Comment: Replacing the red dashes with the correct number should nudge you towards the hidden phrase.